including file from wrong path when compiling opencv on windows
I'm trying to upgrade my opencv version to 4.10, from sources, on windows. But the compilation for msvc is failing.
I have to build two sub-versions, one for gcc (MSYS2) and one for msvc. For each build I'm using different cmake build trees and install directories.
I'm using the NMake generator, with cl as native compiler.
I could compile the first one but when I'm trying to compile the msvc-compliant version at the step:
Building CXX object modules/imgcodecs/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgcodecs.dir/src/loadsave.cpp.obj

It tries to include vcruntime.h (from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\ directory) but then it starts to include files from my MSYS2 package directories (the first one being ...\msys64\ucrt64\include\sal.h). Then compilation is failing with undefined symbols (such as uintptr_t).
Before this point many other opencv files have been compiled, which also include vcruntime.h. They also include sal.h then but from msvc directories.
Only loadsave.cpp behaves differently.
In my PATH, msvc tools path are before my MSYS2 ones and my INCLUDE environment variable only contains msvc paths.
Appart from temporarily removing all MSYS2 related environment variables, what can I do to fix that?

My advice is to do the msvc build from an official Visual Studio x64 native tools command prompt with no msys2 stuff in the path. If there is remove it. I setup a profile in Microsoft Terminal that executes the "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvars64.bat" script in a cmd.exe

@derscherjm makes me wonder: I couldn't see any msys2 stuff in my procedure, EXCEPT that I'm using cmake from msys2. I can't see how but is it possible that it messed up the search for includes? BTW I'm working in a powershell terminal and indeed execute this script before working.

I believe the cmake in msys2 has the msys2 paths for include and libraries in its search.

@derscherjm Using a clean windows install of cmake, cleaning the build tree and starting again gives the exact same behavior...
